# Making sure that a path does not break out of a base path

Tags: security, path, filepath

In a web application, I get a path from the request, which I then append to a (*safe*) base path.
The web application has the full control over the files inside of the base path, but is not allowed to *break out* of it.

I need to make sure that the resulting path (base path + get path) is *inside* the base path.

Is it safe (and enough) to check if the path is valid by:

- replacing all `\` by `/`,
- split by `/`,
- if any chunk is equal to `..` mark the path as invalid?

If the path is not valid it's simply refused, otherwise I create or delete the file with the given path (depending on the action...)

Some further information:

- The *system* does not provide a *good* way to normalize the path.
- I don't expect any valid reason for a path to contain a *back path* (`/../`). The client needs to *normalize* the path before sending it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way within the Unix/Windows/MacOS systems I'm familiar with for the methodology you're talking about to go wrong.  That said, it's fundamentally a low reliability methodology that's completely vulnerable to obscure corner cases in, or changes to, the software that translates your filenames into file system locations.  I would always prefer to use actual file system routines to fully resolve the path and then verify that that is present within the area you want.